# iOS custom movement animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am implementing a custom segmented controller via two buttons.  Each will be a circle, and the selected one will be filled.  I would like to animate the selection of a button so that the "fill" appears to move from one to the other.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  Should I just use a UIView behind?

Comment: I would use a custom `drawRect`, but you could do shape animations.  It may not be as customizable, but could do what you want and be more efficient in doing so.